# Foreign Key constraint - Pentaho

Tags: foreign-key-relationship, etl, pentaho

I'm using Pentaho for my ETL process and I'm having an issue inserting a flat file into a table with a primary key and foreign key relationship.  The transformation is fairly straight forward having a Microsoft Excel Input, Add Constants, and Table Output transformations.  The error I'm getting is "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint".  I believe that you can use a insert/update output transformation but the performance is awful.  Please provide suggestions on how to resolve.

primary_key = Staff_key
foreign_key = Staff_profil_key

Comment: You could disable the constraint before you bulk load and then enable back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table output transformation has an option to ignore insert errors.  You can check this option to ignore the constraint.  This option can not be used in conjunction with the batch update thus affecting performance.